# Trying to return student's GPA during given timespan by Creating a function receiving error message expecting (;) and I have semicolon stating end

Tags: mysql, function

My Input parameters are StudentID int, ClassStartDateStart datetime, ClassStartDateEnd datetime. trying to get Output GPA for all classes taken by student within the ClassStartDateStart and ClassStartDateEnd.

Function script  below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `totalAssignmentGrades` (studentID int,ClassStartDateStart datetime, ClassStartDateEnd datetime)
RETURNS INTEGER
BEGIN
DECLARE StartDate datetime;
DECLARE ClassGPA dec
SELECT StudentID; Receiving error stating that expecting (;)
FROM student_classes 
WHERE StartDate BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-12-31';
```

Could someone Please tell me what I am missing to retrieve the numbers the GPA for student during the given date line.
RETURN (*);

Comment: try "Declare ClassGPA dec;"

Comment: When I do this I get an error at my FROM student_classes statement